# Wrong datetime when exporting from sharepoint to excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I'm using `oDataFeed` to retrieve sharepoint list data and place it in excel sheet. One of the fields in the list is date time field. I have noticed that the date is correct in the list but not on the excel sheet. 
For example, list shows `2/25/2016 12:00 AM` and excel shows `2/24/2016 9:00 PM`.

What's the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you see the date on the form into your local timezone. And most likely SharePoint service you are consuming is returning UTC date. Not 100% sure, you might check. What is the difference between your timezone and UTC?

Comment: 3 hours difference. i have noticed this pattern too but how do I fix it?

Comment: i have created a column with formula that adds +3 hours to the date but is there any other way to fix it like in sharepoint?

Comment: Not sure about Excel. In JavaScript you can get the difference using getTimezoneOffset. But why you import data into Excel using oDataFeed?